# Как включить и настроить логирование базовой авторизации apache2

Tags: debian, apache2

Не могу поймать в логах сообщения о ошибках авторизации `apache2`
В `apache2.conf` прописано `LogLevel info`

В моем случае лог по авторизации пишется не в

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

а по пути

```
/var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.error.log
```

И прилетает туда строка вида

```
2019/09/13 20:00:11 [error] 31919#31919: *5252 user "admin": password mismatch, client: 82.102.24.20, server: site.ru, request: "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"
```

Включение `LogLevel authz_core:debug` добавляет огромную кучу мусора, которую `fail2ban` как минимум не понимает.

```
apache-auth.conf

failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH(01797|01630): )?client denied by server configuration: (uri )?\S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01617: )?user .*? authentication failure for "\S*": Password Mismatch(, referer: \S+)?$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01618: )?user .*? not found(: )?\S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01614: )?client used wrong authentication scheme: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH\d+: )?Authorization of user \S+ to access \S* failed, reason: .*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH0179[24]: )?(Digest: )?user .*?: password mismatch: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH0179[01]: |Digest: )user `.*?' in realm `.+' (not found|denied by provider): \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01631: )?user .*?: authorization failure for "\S*":(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01775: )?(Digest: )?invalid nonce .* received - length is not \S+(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01788: )?(Digest: )?realm mismatch - got `.*?' but expected `.+'(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01789: )?(Digest: )?unknown algorithm `.*?' received: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01793: )?invalid qop `.*?' received: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01777: )?(Digest: )?invalid nonce .*? received - user attempted time travel(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH02486: )?realm mismatch - got `.*' but no realm specified\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LogLevel authz_core:debug
```

Или в вашем случае, чтобы сохранить дефолтный вывод в логи:

```
LogLevel info authz_core:debug
```

Comment: Включение LogLevel authz_core:debug добавляет огромную кучу мусора, которую fail2ban как минимум не понимает.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь эмм... а откуда взялся fail2ban? Вроде ничего в вопросе про его существование не упоминалось...

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь В любом случае, нет гарантии, что ваш fail2ban имеет  regex pattren (failregex) для этих логов вашего Апача, чтобы правильно отфильтровать. Например, моя версия fail2ban имеет кучу паттернов в apache-auth.conf, но ни один не совпадает с тем, что пишет Апач. Следовательно, мне надо самому писать необходимое регулярное выражение.

Comment: https://codeby.net/blogs/kak-nastroit-fail2ban-dlja-zashhity-servera-apache-http/ Ни слова про то что надо что то писать отдельно. И регулярки все есть.

Comment: Регулярки из apache-auth.conf добавил в пост. Вопрос, зачем они там, если апачь не умеет вести логи нужным образом...

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь "зачем они там, если апачь не умеет вести логи нужным образом" - могу предположить, что мейнтейнеры Апача в курсе про существование такого софта, как fail2ban. А логирование в модулях Апача написано на их личное усмотрение, без оглядки на кого-либо. Так что это не Апач "не умеет", а фэйлТуБан не успевает за изменениями.